# Automapper UseDestinationValue

Tags: c#, automapper

Having a problem with a mapping

```
VPerson vPerson = new VPerson() { Id = 2, Lastname = "Hansen1", Name = "Morten1" };
DPerson dPerson = new DPerson() { Id = 1, Lastname = "Hansen", Name = "Morten" };

Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
     //x.AllowNullDestinationValues = true; // does exactly what it says (false by default)
});

Mapper.CreateMap();

Mapper.CreateMap()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

dPerson = Mapper.Map<VPerson, DPerson>(vPerson);
```

`dPerson` is 0, I would think it should be 1, or am I missing something?

Working example

```
VPerson vPerson = new VPerson() { Id = 2, Lastname = "Hansen1", Name = "Morten1" };
        DPerson dPerson = new DPerson() { Id = 1, Lastname = "Hansen", Name = "Morten" };

        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            //x.AllowNullDestinationValues = true; // does exactly what it says (false by default)
        });

        Mapper.CreateMap<DPerson, VPerson>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<VPerson, DPerson>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());


        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        dPerson = Mapper.Map(vPerson, dPerson);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never used the UseDestinationValue() option, but it looks like you just want to NOT map the Id when going from VPerson to DPerson.  If that is the case, use the Ignore option:

```
.ForMember(d => d.Id, o => o.Ignore());
```

**EDIT**

Oh shoot -- I didn't even notice the syntax you were using.  You need to use the overload of "Map" that accepts the existing destination object:

```
Mapper.Map(vPerson, dPerson);
```

The version you're using creates a new DPerson and then performs the mappings.  The one I show above takes the already-created dPerson and then performs the mappings (and with the Ignore option shown above, your Id is not overwritten).

Comment: I get the same result if I use this option

Comment: Now it works with UseDestinationValue, thank you so much for your help :-)